# Why doesn't <img> flex item shrink, but div flex item does?

Tags: css, flexbox

Given the following markup and css ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aryzing/p6nmxj6L/)), why does the second `.bingo` div comply to it's parents hight, but not the `<img>`?

```
<div class='root1'>
  <div class='child'>
    <img class='bingo' src="http://www.audubon.org/sites/default/files/styles/engagement_card/public/sfw_apa_2013_28342_232388_briankushner_blue_jay_kk_high.jpg?itok=ttMfUhUu">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='root2'>
  <div class='child'>
    <div class='bingo'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.root1, .root2 {
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.root1 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.root2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.child {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.bingo {
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div.bingo {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why it's happening, but the fix is `width: 100%;` on the `img`.

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `.bingo`. https://jsfiddle.net/p6nmxj6L/1/